# 'longer-term/lower-coupon bonds' vs 'shorter-term/higher-coupon bonds'

Tags: interest-rate, bonds

> [[Source:]](http://business.financialpost.com/investing/stocks-bonds-interest-rates/)  [Arthur Salzer](https://ca.linkedin.com/in/arthursalzer), B.A. Econ. (McMaster University), CFA, CIM
>
> “Remember that longer-term/lower-coupon bonds go down more in price than shorter-term/higher-coupon bonds do when interest rates rise,” he said.

Could someone please explain the quote above? Why's it true?

Answer (score 4):

- When the coupon is high, any change in interest rate is *relatively* less important. For example, if you have a 10% coupon and interest rates rise from 0% to 1%, your absolute RoI is still 9%, not a huge change. But if the coupon was only 2%, your RoI got *halved*
- With short term bonds, interest rates matter less because you can always hold a bond to maturity, and the return of the principal makes up a much greater part of the value of the bond than the coupon.